# How to increase SQL_ACTIVE_STATEMENTS LIMIT

Tags: java, teradata

My code runs well for small number of queries

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < queries.length ; i ++ ) {
        PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement(queries[i]);
        if (queries[i].toUpperCase().contains("SELECT ") && !queries[i].toUpperCase().contains("CREATE ") && !queries[i].toUpperCase().contains("DROP ") && !queries[i].toUpperCase().contains("DELETE "))
        {  rs=stmt.executeQuery(); }
        else {stmt.executeUpdate();}
    }
```

I came around the following error for the 16th statement i guess

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: 
[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Beyond SQL_ACTIVE_STATEMENTS limit
```

How can I increase the `SQL_ACTIVE_STATEMENTS` limit

I tried

```
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl,user,password);
    conn.setHoldability(20);
    conn.setClientInfo( //
```

Comment: How to increase SQL_ACTIVE_STATEMENTS LIMIT? Closing the statements as soon as you're finished with them, I don't know why you're not closing each `PreparedStatement` when you're finished using it.

Comment: @Ashot Karakhanyan please don't change the code in a question.

Comment: I changed only indentation not the logic, but if you don't want it's your choice.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan well, it is remarkable then that this appeared in your edit: `public static void main(String[] args) {`. Again, please do not add code with an edit.

Comment: ok, it was mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. Your problem is not modifying `SQL_ACTIVE_STATEMENTS LIMIT` (which btw looks like a constant and thus cannot be changed) but closing each statement when you're finished using it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queries[i]);
        try {          
            if (queries[i].toUpperCase().contains("SELECT ") && !queries[i].toUpperCase().contains("CREATE ") && !queries[i].toUpperCase().contains("DROP ") && !queries[i].toUpperCase().contains("DELETE ")) {
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            } else {
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        } finally {
            stmt.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Just keep in mind that closing a statement also closes any associated `ResultSet` (which btw you're not declaring anywhere).